# Customize an android spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I m trying to customize a spinner so that it has a image as selector instead of radio buttons(default). I am referring to this [blog](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57). But it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions on how to proceed or link to a tutorial would also be great.
i get the following errors:

> No resource identifier found for
>   attribute 'spinnerSelector' in package
>   'android'
>
> No resource found that matches the
>   given name (at 'drawable' with value
>   '@drawable/btn_dropdown_down

'

```
 <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=""
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/spinnerCompletedStatus" android:spinnerSelector="@drawable/myspinner_selector"
                         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"  />
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I see the XML where your Spinner is declared?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the native Spinner style:

```
<style name="Widget.Spinner">
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_dropdown</item>
<item name="android:clickable">true</item>
<item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
<item name="android:dropDownSelector"> @android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
<item name="android:popupBackground"> @android:drawable/spinner_dropdown_background</item>
<item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-10dip</item>
<item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
<item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:popupPromptView">@android:layout/simple_dropdown_hint</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

and then at drawable/btn_dropdown, drawable/list_selector_background, drawable/spinner_dropdown_background files -> you can come to a conclusion that you need:
- btn_dropdown*.png 
- list_selector_background*.png
- spinner_dropdown_background*.png
files, from all the folders like drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi  etc.
And then add your xml style to your project.